# passing variables in url in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to pass variable to another page via url.

Here is the main page. Below I am retrieving title row from the table and what I want to have on the next page is to show the actual title data not something like secongpage.php?id=1234. something like secondpage.php/title=something

```
echo "<div>"
       ."<a href=''>"
         .wordwrap($row['title'], 35, "<br />\n", true)."
       </a>"."
     </div>"."\n";
```

here is secondpage.php `$_GET['title']` isn't defined, I just put it there so to use it incase I get the variable passed from index.php.

```
<?php
    $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test  where title =".$_GET['title']" order by id  ";
    $result = $mydb->query( $sql );
    if ( !$result ) {
       echo $mydb->error;
    }
 ?> 
 <div>
    <?php
       while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
          echo $row['firstname'];
       }
       $mydb->close();
    ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your link to:

```
echo "<div>
       <a href='secondpage.php?title=".rawurlencode($row['title'])."'>
        ".wordwrap($row['title'], 35, "<br />\n", true)."
       </a>
     </div>";
```

And do this in your secondpage.php

```
$sql = "
      SELECT *
      FROM test  
      where title =".mysql_real_escape_string(rawurldecode($_GET['title']))." order by id";
```

Comment: thanks but the what I meant was like the actual title. the one that I am displaying.

Comment: thanks but why am I getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" order by id "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) ` error. could you see what's wrong?

Comment: `".$_GET['title']"` should be `".$_GET['title']."` . You forgot a string operator there

Comment: and also don't forgot to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid sql injection bug when passing variable to sql query. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php